# Using more than one model for entity extraction- OpenNLP

Tags: java, machine-learning, nlp, opennlp, uima

I have two model files as: 1)en-politicians-ner.bin 2)en-engineers-ner.bin

Now, is there a way to add these two models in a **single NameFinderME object**. Work around for using these two models may be to create two NameFinderME objects and Iterate over it to extract entities, But I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 3):

From the book [Taming Text](http://www.manning.com/ingersoll/):

```
NameFinderME[] finders = new NameFinderME[3];
    String[] names = {"person", "location", "date"};
    for (int mi = 0; mi < names.length; mi++) {
      finders[mi] = new NameFinderME(new TokenNameFinderModel(
          new FileInputStream(
              new File(modelDir, "en-ner-" + names[mi] + ".bin")
          )));
```

}

Comment: This is exactly what the question author was explicitly **not** asking for.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is, in other words, a means to combine two models into one. As far as I know (I'm not a great expert on this), this is generally not possible for statistical NLP models.

The only chance I see to pack the two models into one is to somehow get your hands on both of the training data sets used to train the two models and then re-train a new model from the combined training sets.

If you don't have access to the training sets, this is of course no option for you. But even if you had, I don't really see the fundamental advantage of this approach over just using two `NameFinder`s.

Comment: What I thought was, If I don't have any option to combine two models as one, I can pass a model to a NameFinder(instance) and another model to other NameFinder(instance). So now I have two of my models loaded, and now I'll pass the input to the first NameFinder it'll identify the entities trained in first model, also I can pass the input to second NameFinder to get entities trained in second model.